# Build Yii2 Search Query

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to build the query for search, here it is

```
        $searchResult = Candidate::find()
        ->select('HRMS_candidateID, HRMS_candidateFirstName','HRMS_candidateMiddleName')
        ->where(['LIKE', 'HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills', $keywordsArrayTrimed[$i]])

        ->all();
```

As I have `$keywordsArrayTrimed[$i]` which contains keywords, the number count of keywords is different on each request how to achieve this.

I have tried using for loop, it throes an error `Unexpected for loop`.

I tired using filter Like this

```
 $searchResult->andFilterWhere([
            'or',
            ['like', 'HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills', $keywordsArrayTrimed[$i]],

        ]);
```

It didn't work. Please Help.

Comment: Show us your loop, and add details about $keywordsArrayTrimed

Comment: @soju Added for Loop

Comment: $keywordsArrayTrimed is array of words

Comment: Well, you should learn php before using a php framework

Comment: @soju Thanks and I will take care next time before post any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply try this :

```
// build condition
$condition = ['or'];
foreach ($keywordsArrayTrimed as $keyword) {
    $condition[] = ['like', 'HRMS_candidatePrimarySkills', $keyword];
}

// fetch results
$searchResult = Candidate::find()->where($condition)->all();
```